React useState hook is not updated
When I run my frontend and backend, Axios makes a request to the specified route and logs the status of the response as '200' to the console. However, even after that, the 'auth' state does not update. How can I fix this issue?
//PrivateRoute.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/users/protected', {withCredentials: true});
        console.log('Status: ', response.status)
        if (response.status === 200) {
            setAuth(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
            setAuth(false);
      }
    };
    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  console.log('Auth: ', auth);
  return auth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;

Status: 200
Auth: false
//Expecting
Auth: true
//Result
Auth: false

<Navigate to="/" /> You're navigating away, so by the time the response comes back, you're not on this page any more. You'll need to add a loading state, and stay here (eg, return null) if it's still loading.
